# how to hide the first two tables inside a div

Tags: html, css, dom

I have the following left navigation menu inside my SharePoint web application:-

[image]

Now i want to hide the first two tables inside the Div (named; Documents & Images), i tried the following but it have only deleted the "Documents" table:-

```
#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView > table:first-child { display: none !important;}
```

can anyone advice on this please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:nth-child(n)` selector, where `n` is the element's position index in the container, so:

```
#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView > table:nth-child(1),
#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView > table:nth-child(2) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: also, nth-child(2-n)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like the example below and you're good to go.

```
#your-div-name > table:nth-of-type(-n+2){
    display: none;
  }
```

[See working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/gShcy/126/)